# Conditionally position and display sprite given iphone different sizes in cocos2d 2

Tags: ios, ios5, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

I created an app that is compatible for iOS 5 and pre iPhone 5. Meaning, its background and sprites positioning are the way they are supposed to for the iPhone 3.5 Retina. When I tried running my app on the iPhone 4" Retina, I see black padding on the top and bottom of my app. I was trying to find a smart way to conditionally display different background and sprite positioning given the size of the screen. I tried these two ways and they are not returning the value that I expect....

```
NSLog(@"Win Height: %f", winSize.height);
NSLog(@"Win Width: %f", winSize.width);
NSLog(@"Main Screen Height: %f", [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);
NSLog(@"Main Screen Width: %f", [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);


2012-10-02 21:36:47.317 Win Height: 480.000000
2012-10-02 21:36:47.318 Win Width: 320.000000
2012-10-02 21:36:47.319 Main Screen Height: 480.000000
2012-10-02 21:36:47.319 Main Screen Width: 320.000000
```

Does anyone know a way to conditionally position sprite given the size of the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the Default-568h@2x.png splash image to disable letterboxing?

Once that is done you could do something like this,

```
#define DEVICE_IS_IPHONE5 ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)

if(DEVICE_IS_IPHONE5)
{
     //Do something different
}
else
{
}
```

Edit: Forgot the @2x

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for the reply. The NSLog that I specified on my question was outputed when I was using iPhone 6 simulator with 4" Retina display. It was saying that the height was 480....

Comment: Then you haven't included an iPhone 5 splash screen. The app is still letterboxed. You need a splash name Default-568h.png in your bundle.

Comment: Sorry, that should be Default-568h@2x.png